# Using gulp to include node modules

Tags: javascript, gulp

Most Gulp tutorials follow roughly the same pattern: the developer writes a gulp file, in this gulp file the developer imports some plugin -eg: js uglify-
and use it to build the output file.

My question is a bit different and though I know it is elementary, I can't find a solution. Let's say I wrote a script "X" which relies on jQuery to work. I have installed jQuery via NPM, now how would I include it when running gulp? Right now I list in the gulpfile all the external JS -and CSS, and fonts and images- I need and use streamqueue to merge everything. It kind of works, but it feels more like a workaround than an actual solution. Is there any way to tell Gulp to automatically include any dependency, as they are listed in package.json?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

This example is configured for developing React project and using Gulp task runners and npm packages.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
// New Plugin
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var util = require('gulp-util');
var watchify = require('watchify')
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');


gulp.task('browserify' , function(){
  return browserify('./scripts/main.js')
        .transform(babelify , {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
        .bundle()
        .on('error' , function(e) {
          console.log(e.message);

          this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        // .pipe(buffer())
        // .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});


gulp.task('watch' , ['browserify'],  function() {
  gulp.watch('./scripts/**/*/*.js' , ['browserify']);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/antd.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app">

    </div>

  <script src="build/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "reactproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.5",
    "browserify": "^13.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^2.6.4",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "react-cookie": "^1.0.4",
    "react-mixin": "^3.0.5",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

**Project Structure:**

```
├── build
├── node_modules
├── scripts
├── styles
gulpfile.js
index.html
package.json
package-lock.json
```